# When revoke a method in Class definition, what's the difference between custom defined class and the ruby reserved class such as `Class` or `Object`

Tags: ruby, class

I'm ruby newbie, I am learning some ruby's basic knowledge such as class inheritance.

I write some snippets to deepen my understanding, but the bellow 2 snippets make me very confused.

```
class Object
  def hello_o
    puts "Hello in Object"
  end

  hello_o
end
```

This one print "Hello in Object" while

```
class A
  def hello_a
    puts "Hello in A"
  end

  hello_a
end
```

this one throw me an error:

`undefined local variable or method hello_a' for A:Class`

Why? I think both `A` and `Object` is class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the first example, you defined an instance method `hello_o` on class `Object`, and called it from `Object`, which is an instance of `Class` class, which inherits `Object` class, so it worked.

With your second example, you defined an instance method `hello_a` of class `A`, and tried to call it from `A`, which is an instance of `Class` class, which does not inherit `A` class, so it failed.

Comment: I got it. Actually, when I call `hello_o` in `Object`,  It's the same with `Object.hello_o`, so the `Object` in `Object.hello_o` is an object, it instantiated from `Class` while `Class` inherited from `Object` and the method `hello_o` already defined in the first snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You are dynamically adding a method to the `Object` class, which is the root of the object hierarchy. therefore, anything that subclasses `Object` (which is everything, implicitly) will have that method available to it. That's why you're allowed to call it in your class definition.

```
class Object
  def hello_o
    puts "Hello in Object"
  end

  hello_o
end

class A
end

A.hello_o    # this will work
```